# How to create this detergent bottle recipient

Tags: modeling, objects, topology

I want to create this laundry detergent bottle recipient, but I can't go on modelling because I don't know how to create these shapes

[image]

I have attached here my [Blender file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1u2Vw22BcsraC2v1QJD86GZtS_QEXPGI8/view?usp=sharing)

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could begin with some extrusion along the bottle design, like that:

[image]

Extrude to give it thickness:

[image]

Move some faces backwards or forwards, create some new edge loops, etc...

[image]

To answer [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/258446/modeling-a-detergent-bottle), follow the same kind of steps, begin with the silhouette::

[image]

Extrude:

[image]

Then push and pull some edges and faces, etc:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Topology can be hard.

In this case, you'd typically use a subdivision surface modifier to create extra geometry and to help create the creases and relief.

In principle, however, you basically want an edge loop to flow along contours like the ones you highlighted, similar to how you have already done it in the left hand side of your attempt. You need to continue it around that bottom corner, following the crease.

You typically then combine this with supporting loops (edge loops that run parallel to the first) once you've established the difference in depth between the two areas. The closer these supporting edges are, the sharper they'll appear with your subdivision surface modifier.

With this in mind, I'd start with my supporting loops close together along the left edge then space them out a bit as they go around the corner to increase the width of the crease and smooth it out.

Play around with it and don't be afraid of making mistakes.

I'd also be tempted to revisit that handle - maybe place your reference picture in behind/in front of your model to compare the shapes.